# Angular Service call after variable population

Tags: angularjs, promise, lazy-loading, angular-promise, angular-services

I'm trying to create an angular service that holds a variable which value in turn will be set after result of another service call. Here is the  code:

```
angular.module("someApp",[]).service("someServiceName", function() {

  var myVar = undefined;

  this.get = function() {
    if (myVar) {
      return myVar
    } else {
      console.error('Error text');
    }
  }

  var init = function () {
    anotherService.call().then(function (result) {
      myVar = result;
    });
  };

  init();
});
```

When I call **someServiceName.get()** first time after application load it returns nothing (because myVar is not filled yet). But on next service call it returns value if myVar variable.
So, my question is how to return **myVar** on **someServiceName.get()** call but after running **init()** first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are calling *someServiceName.get()* before the *anotherService.call()* is ended; this will give you **undefined**.

What about:

```
angular.module("someApp",[]).service("someServiceName", function($q) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  this.get = function() {
     anotherService.call()
       .then(function (result) {
          if (result) {
             deferred.resolve(result);
          } else {
             deferred.reject('Error text');
          }
       }, function (error) {
          deferred.reject('AnotherService error');
       });
     return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```

In this case you will recall the *anotherService* each time you want to get his value.

Comment: thanks for your response. I ended up with another solution, but your method also works for my problem :)